# How to handle bad signal / internet connection with Volley?

Tags: java, android, httprequest, android-volley

I've recently switched from a old apache library to Volley, but I can't get it to work in a similar way.

I'm trying to send requests to a endpoint with Volley, but I realized problems might occur when the phone doesn't have good signal / internet connection. I don't want the server to get spammed with the queued requests, but I also want a request to be sent as soon as the internet connection allows it.

How does one handle loss of connection for a longer period of time with Volley without overwhelming the server and still maintaining the possibility of the request being sent to the server as soon as the connection is good enough?

I've tried using Network Link Conditioner to simulate a bad connection (65% packet loss) while timing how long it takes for the request to go through and the apache-requests seems to go through alot faster without spamming the server with requests.

Below is the code I'm currently using:

```
while(requestNotConfirmedOnServer()) {
    numberOfTries++;
    if(numberOfTries <= Constants.ADD_ALARM_RETRIES) {
        final CaStringRequest stringRequest = new CaStringRequest(_context, Request.Method.GET, false, addURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        wsRequestIsInProgress = false;
                        //Handle response
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        wsRequestIsInProgress = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "VolleyError: " + error);
                    }
                });

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, 0, 1f));
        if(requestNotConfirmedOnServer()) {
            CARequestQueue.getInstance(_context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            wsRequestIsInProgress = true;
        }

        try {
            while(wsRequestIsInProgress) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            Thread.sleep(Constants.ADD_ALARM_RETRY_TIMEOUT);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            ApplicationManager.getInstance(_context).printLog(TAG, "Error while putting thread to sleep: ");
        }
  }
}
```

Also, the old apache code:

```
while(requestNotConfirmedOnServer()){
    try{
    String addURL = "http..."
        ApplicationManager.getInstance(_context).printLog(TAG, addURL);
        CCResponse response= new WebServicesManager().sendHttpRequest(_context, addURL);

        if(response.get_httpCode()==HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            String[] responseParts = response._responseString.split(";");
      //Handle Response
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        ApplicationManager.getInstance(_context).printLog(TAG, "Error: ");
    }
    ApplicationManager.getInstance(_context).printLog(TAG, "Putting thread to sleep.");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(Constants.ADD_ALARM_SLEEP_INTERVAL);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ApplicationManager.getInstance(_context).printLog(TAG, "Error while putting thread to sleep: ");
    }
}


//From WebServiceManager
public CCResponse sendHttpPostOrRequest(Context context, String relativeURL, String postData) {
  CCResponse ccResponse;
  try {
    String finalURL = "http://....";
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
          HttpResponse response = null;
          if(postData != null){
              HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(finalURL);
              List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", postData));
              httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
              response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
          }else {
              response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(finalURL));
          }
          HttpEntity resEntityGet = response.getEntity();
          String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet, "UTF-8");
          ccResponse = new CCResponse(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), responseString);
    Log.d(TAG, responseString);
  }catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
    ccResponse = new CCResponse(-1, "Exception " + e);
  }
  return  ccResponse;
}
```

Comment: When you do this, have you checked the server logs to see how the server is doing?

Comment: Not an answer but OkHttp may serve you better here than Volley. It does retries automatically by default and in my experience is easier to use.